# Python: Parse timestamp string with 7 digits for microseconds to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, strptime

I have a timestamp string that looks like this:

```
2019-02-16T10:41:20.6080000+01:00
```

I have to parse it to datetime. Because there are 7 instead of 6 digits for microseconds the following format does not match:

```
timestamp = "2019-03-14T14:37:37.000000+01:00"
parsed_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z") #ValueError: time data '2019-03-14T14:37:37.0000000+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

How can I parse this format?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Do you only want the date from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`dparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dt_1 = '2019-02-16T10:41:20.6080000+01:00'
print("Datetime: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Datetime: 2019-02-16 10:41:20.608000+01:00
```

If you want the date component:

```
print("Date: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).date()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Date: 2019-02-16
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use simple string slicing.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
timestamp = "2019-02-16T10:41:20.6080000+01:00"
parsed_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp[:26], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").date() 

print(parsed_timestamp)
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-16
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two things wrong with your data: you have seven digits for microseconds, *and* your timezone has a colon.

I would use a regex to solve this problem:

```
timestamp = "2019-02-16T10:41:20.6080000+01:00"
cleaned_timestamp = re.sub('(\d{6})\d(\+\d{2})(:)(\d{2})', r'\1\2\4', timestamp)
parsed_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(cleaned_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
parsed_timestamp
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 10, 41, 20, 608000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```